# unable to get nested formControlName ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-template, formarray

I am unable to add new textfield on button click

here is my code i have tired,

**home.ts**

```
constructor() {
  this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    md: false,
    mdNames: this._fb.group({
      uid: "",
      _rev: "",
      type: "i_org_docs_ref",
      name: "MARINE1",
      details: "Material declaration",
      details_array: this._fb.array([]),
      cdt: ""
    }),
  });

}


addClicked() {

  const control2 = <
    FormArray( < FormGroup > this.myForm.controls['mdNames']).controls['details_array']

  control2.push(this._fb.group({
    mdTextBox: "",
  }));
}
```

**home.html**

```
<div formControlName="mdNames">
  <div formArrayName="details_array">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm.controls.details_array.controls; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <ion-item no-lines>
          <button 
            ion-button 
            color="dark" 
            clear 
            icon-only 
            item-end 
            class="deleteBtn"
            (click)="deleteOrgItemClicked(i)">
                    <ion-icon name="ios-trash"></ion-icon>
                </button>
          <ion-input 
            formControlName="mdTextBox" 
            type="text" 
            class="textFields" 
            placeholder="Type details">
          </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <button 
        (click)="addClicked()" 
        class="addBtn">
            Add documents
        </button>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display values of **details_array** but it shows this error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'mdNames'

***Please help where i am making mistake?***

Comment: please refer this Example -[Inline Link](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2018-02-06-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-input-fields-with-ionic/)

Comment: Example shows formarray inside formgroup. my question is one step more like formarray inside formgroup of formgroup

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-i6wdtm)

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <div formGroupName="mdNames">
            <div formArrayName="details_array">
                <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm.controls.mdNames.controls.details_array.controls; let i=index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <ion-item no-lines>
                            <button ion-button color="dark" clear icon-only item-end class="deleteBtn" (click)="deleteOrgItemClicked(i)">
                                                <ion-icon name="ios-trash"></ion-icon>
                                            </button>

                            <ion-input formControlName="mdTextBox" type="text" class="textFields" placeholder="Type details"></ion-input>

                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                </ion-list> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-item>
            <button (click)="addClicked()" class="addBtn">
                Add documents
            </button>
        </ion-item>

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
details_array: FormArray;

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      md: false,
      mdNames: this._fb.group(
        {
          uid: "",
          _rev: "",
          type: "i_org_docs_ref",
          name: "MARINE1",
          details: "Material declaration",
          details_array: this._fb.array([this.createArray()]),
          cdt: ""
        }
      ),
    });

  }
  createArray(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      name: 'myName',
      data: 'myData',
      mdTextBox: 'mdTextBox'
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but control is breaking at first line of template i.3 here: `<div formControlName="mdNames">`

Comment: Check Edited Code.

Comment: I have taken only one formgroup inside form array